# Removing a control that has focus with the click of a button in c sharp

Tags: c#, button, focus, controls

I have several controls in a panel, and I want to make a button that removes the one that has focus at the time that the button get clicked. I tried iterating through the controls in the panel to check if any of them has focus, but it always evaluates to false. I suspect that this is because the button gets focus as soon as it is clicked. If this is what is happening, can someone please tell me how I can keep track of the last control in the panel to have focus. Maybe an event every time focus changes? And if this is not what is happening, can someone please tell me what they think is happening. Thank you in advance.

Comment: just thinking on the top of my head, you could add some store the id of control in some hidden value via jquery, on focus, and in codebehind compare controls' clientId property to check.

Comment: @iamserious: I'm pretty sure this is a Winforms app, not an ASP.NET one.

Comment: oh, okay, but how did you guys know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right -- as soon as the button is pressed, all the other controls will lose focus.

You can work around this by listening for the [GotFocus event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx) to remember which was the most recently selected one. For example:

```
public partial class YourForm
{
    private Control _LastFocusedControl;

    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var controlsToWatchForFocusChange = ...;   // Some IEnumerable<Control>, e.g. `new[] { txtTextBox1, txtTextBox2 }`
        foreach (var control in controlsToWatchForFocusChange) {
            control.GotFocus += (sender, e) => _LastFocusedControl = (Control)sender;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when your button is pressed, the last control to have focus will be accessible via `_LastFocusedControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the button has the focus since it was just clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx) and [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) events to keep track of which control was focused before the button was pressed.

Comment: Thank you. So my plan right now is to use the LostFocus event to keep track of which was the last control in the form to have focus before the button click. If it was one of the controls in the panel, then that one will get removed.